# subset dataframe, based on min()

Tags: r, function

I am trying to establish a function, that uses y argument to subset a dataframe and then calculate the min of the `y.p` column. The minimum of `y.p` column is then used to subset the same dataframe in regard to column `c`.

```
b <- function (y) {
    df<- read.csv("C:/../.csv", colClasses="character")
    y.p<-paste("d",y, sep=".")
    minimum=min(min.outcome<-as.numeric(data.frame[,y.p]),na.rm=T)
    df[df$y.p==minimum,"c"]
}
```

here is a part of the dataframe: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3152d1ki1ot232/Classeur2.csv

After running the function, I am getting `character(0)` as result !

I have tested the function line by line and the error seems to be in the last line..

May you help me solve this issue plz ?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please add a sample of the `data.frame` being read in with `read.csv()` (using `dput()` for example)? It's difficult to trace the source of the error without being able to actually test your function.

Comment: Try to not use define a variable name as a R function, ie `data.frame()`. You are essentially trying to extract the row values of column `c` when column `a...r.y` is minimized. You don't need a roundabout function to do this.

Comment: @Vlo: I used roundabout bcoz this function is meant to add a specific character vector as y argument.. however, the roundabout seems to work well.. I think the error is more in the 4th line..

Comment: @nrussell: I have just added the link for the dataframe. Thx again.

Comment: what exact command is giving you `character(0)`? It seems you are always putting your column name in the formal `d.[y]` however your csv only has one such column. Also, be careful that as.numeric() is making the correct values, as they could be resolving to factor levels instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay well to be honest it's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but I think you are looking to be able to pass in a character value to `y` in the event that the data you are reading in has multiple columns beginning with `d.`? Anyways, if this is incorrect, please walk through what you are trying to do step by step.

```
Foo <- function(y){
  df <- read.csv(
    file="G:/Classeur2.csv",
    header=TRUE,
    colClasses=c(
      'numeric',
      rep('character',4))
  )
  ##
  df[,3:5] <- sapply(3:5, function(X){
    df[,X] <- as.numeric(
      gsub("Not Available",NA,df[,X])
    ) 
  })
  ##
  y.p <- paste("d",y,sep=".")
  ypCol <- match(y.p,names(df))
  ##
  minimum <- min(
    df[,ypCol],
    na.rm=TRUE
  )
  ##
  dOut <- df[df[,ypCol]==minimum,"c"]
  dOut <- dOut[!is.na(dOut)]
  return(dOut)
}
##
Foo(y="y")
## [1] "HOSPITAL SYSTEM"
```

Comment: once df[df$y.p==minimum,"c"] became df[df[,ypCol]==minimum,"c"], the exact column was selected and it worked fine !